# I tried to restore my win 7os from a disc image using redo backup but

Tags: windows-7

This is a question referring to win 7 home premium , 64 bit thinkpad t60 laptop which i bought 2nd hand and don't have a serial number.
I tried to restore my win 7os from a disc image using redo backup but half way through the restore I got an error message and it wouldn't continue. Then win 7 wouldn't boot at all. I tried all options on the windows recovery disc but i got a message saying no hdd and another inviting me to install drivers, but i didn't know which ones. I can see my win 7 files from linux so maybe all is not lost.

Thanks for any reply

Michael Kay

Comment: Was the _redo backup_ a backup image that was provided by the seller of the computer, or a backup you made yourself?

Comment: Its a linux based backup program. He dosen't say *what* he used to make the image, and the t60 probably came with XP or vista so it was probably installed by the last user.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Windows 7 installer crashing or hanging part way through.  Turns out the hard drive was failing (had bad sectors).  Run disk diags from the HD manufacturer to test it.  Also, BACK UP your data immediately if you care about it.

Good luck.